# Why does my "printf("%-13s\n", name);" not work

Tags: c

```
    char name[20];
    char last_name[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        strcpy(name, "Firstname");
        strcat(name, "Lastname");
       printf("%-13s\n", name);
    }
```

For some reason when I print out `name` it just prints out `Firstname Lastname` in full instead of cutting it off at 13 characters. Could someone please explain what I did wrong?

I tried modifying the number to 10 and other ones but it still did not work and printed the whole string.

Comment: Yes, I believe so.

Comment: "In no
       case does a nonexistent or small field width cause truncation of
       a field; if the result of a conversion is wider than the field
       width, the field is expanded to contain the conversion result."

Comment: @Harith it would be helpful to say where that quote is coming from.

Comment: `printf("%-13s\n", name);` does work. It outputs the string left-formatted in a field width of 13. If it doesn't fit, it overflows the field width. It is dangerous to truncate the output (as can be done), because the unrepresentative text can mislead the user.

Comment: Spend an hour reading [man 3 printf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) it will save you 10-fold that amount of time and frustration in the future. The same for [man 3 scanf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html). And when I say read, I mean read every word, not just skim and think "yah, I go it...". ... know it ... (apply the same to every aspect of information related to C -- that's how you learn to program in C `:)`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `%.13s` to print at most 13 characters:

```c
printf("%.13s\n", name);
```

Or

```c
printf("%-13.13s\n", name);
```

if you want it to print eactly 13 characters, left aligned

Comment: @RyanTa You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.` in front of the field width specifier to `printf`.

E.g.

```
% cat test.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char *foo = "hello world";
    printf("%.5s\n", foo);
}
% gcc test.c
% ./a.out   
hello
```